# Calculate 2 columns together in Yii2 model::find() function

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2

I have the following working find() function in Yii2:

```
User::find()->select('id, name')->where(['status' => '10'])->all()
```

However, the User model also has the following attributes:

```
'credit'
'ammount'
```

I need to check if the 'ammount' minus 'credit' is more that a value ($price) I am passing to the function.

How can I make a User:find() query where I am only getting the user objects where the amount minus credit is larger than the value I am checking against?

Thanks

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the amount and credit are in the `user` table so you can do something like.

```
User::find()->select([new \yii\db\Expression('id,amount,credit')])
->where(['status' => '10'])
->andWhere('amount - credit > :yourAmount',[':yourAmount'=>$price])
->all();
```

or use `addParams()` to bind the custom value

```
User::find()->select([new \yii\db\Expression('id,amount,credit')])
->where(['status' => '10'])
->andWhere('amount - credit > :yourAmount')
->addParams([':yourAmount'=>$price])
->all();
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great